# Jquery on change event is not triggering when an option is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("Hey remove this alert asap");
   console.log("I am ready now");
   $("#select-box").change(function(){
       console.log("I am in select box change");         
      alert("hello");
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px" name="select-box" id="select-box" class=""><option value="">Select an option</option><option value="all">Select all</option><option value="none">Select none</option></select>
```

I am using jQuery on change event. Even if the option is changed the function is not getting triggered. No errors are showing up in developer tools as well. So i am struck here and not sure why the function is not getting triggered.

I am not able to see any console log messages or the alert as well. Can any one please correct me please.

Comment: It seems to be working as intended here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmZqQZ?editors=1010 Are you loading in the box dynamically?

Comment: You're more than likely not including jQuery check here: https://jsfiddle.net/nnje48bm/

Comment: Yep your code is working as others have pointed out.

Comment: @Rnga check to see that you haven't loaded jquery multiple times - this sometimes mucks things up

Comment: The code looks ok. Is this a stand-alone example or just a snipped from a larger code base?

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the comments. Actually i am adding the select box dynamically from javascript. I have updated the code. Not sure if any of that is causing the problem. I have edited the HTML in the question.

Comment: Its from the larger code base @materialdreams

Comment: How do i check for that? Can you please let me know please? Also i have edited teh html can you please have a look? @RachelGallen

Comment: If you are adding your box dinamically then you need to change the way you add the event listener to the element

Comment: @Rnga look in your <head> section of your html file to see that the link to jquery hasn't been included more than once (sometimes the link may be at the bottom of the html either) Also check for diiferent vsns

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i do that? @Lixus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Is your select wrapped in another element that you can hook the event to?  It could be the `document` but closer is better.

Comment: There seems to be errors in the html code that you posted in your update. I switched the color to black and removed a rogue quote mark. Came up with:  $('#add-box').append('<select style="float:right;margin-right:10px; margin-top:5px" name="tool-menu" id="tool-menu"><option value=" ">Select an option</option><option value="all">Select all</option><option value="none">Select none</option><option value="add-playlist">Add to playlist</option></select><p style="float: right;margin-top: 0px; font-size: 11px; color:black;>Tools</p><div class="content" />');

Comment: Your code is incomplete without the code that adds the select dynamically to your page.  If you use whatever you appended TO as the anchor for the event manager it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the markup for the select dynamically, you should also bind the event dynamically:

```
$(document).on('change', "#select-box", function () {
   console.log("I am in select box change");         
});
```